# How to convert String array to the room entity object i.e DAO in kolin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao, typeconverter

I have response like this :

```
    {
  "response":{"numFound":5303,"start":0,"maxScore":6.5102634,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"10.1371/journal.pone.0000290",
        "journal":"PLoS ONE",
        "eissn":"1932-6203",
        "publication_date":"2007-03-14T00:00:00Z",
        "article_type":"Research Article",
        "author_display":["Rayna I. Kraeva",
          "Dragomir B. Krastev",
          "Assen Roguev",
          "Anna Ivanova",
          "Marina N. Nedelcheva-Veleva",
          "Stoyno S. Stoynov"],
        "abstract":["Nucleic acids, due to their structural and chemical properties, can form double-stranded secondary structures that assist the transfer of genetic information and can modulate gene expression. However, the nucleotide sequence alone is insufficient in explaining phenomena like intron-exon recognition during RNA processing. This raises the question whether nucleic acids are endowed with other attributes that can contribute to their biological functions. In this work, we present a calculation of thermodynamic stability of DNA/DNA and mRNA/DNA duplexes across the genomes of four species in the genus Saccharomyces by nearest-neighbor method. The results show that coding regions are more thermodynamically stable than introns, 3′-untranslated regions and intergenic sequences. Furthermore, open reading frames have more stable sense mRNA/DNA duplexes than the potential antisense duplexes, a property that can aid gene discovery. The lower stability of the DNA/DNA and mRNA/DNA duplexes of 3′-untranslated regions and the higher stability of genes correlates with increased mRNA level. These results suggest that the thermodynamic stability of DNA/DNA and mRNA/DNA duplexes affects mRNA transcription."],
        "title_display":"Stability of mRNA/DNA and DNA/DNA Duplexes Affects mRNA Transcription",
        "score":6.5102634},
```

Now in this I want to get the 'abstract' field. For this I had specified it as String but it gave me error that it the array and can not convert to string.

Now I am not sure how to create object for this which array type I should specify.

I checked that we can use the Type Converters but not able to write the converter for the same.

Following is my object and converter which I tried.

DAO

```
    @Entity(tableName = "news_table")
data class NewsArticles(
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = "",
    @SerializedName("article_type") var title: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("abstract") var description: Array<String>,
    @SerializedName("publication_date") var publishedAt: String? = null
)
```

Type Converter

```
    class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Array<String>?): String? {
        return value?.let { String(it) } //error
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(array: Array<String>): String? {
        return array.toString()
    }
}
```

Its giving me error for return line that none of the following functions can be called with arguments supplied.

EDIT :

now I changed defination to ArrayList
@SerializedName("abstract") var description: ArrayList,

and converter to this

```
    class ArrayConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromArray(value: ArrayList<String>?): String? {
        return value?.let { arrayToString(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun arrayToString(array: ArrayList<String>): String? {
        return array.toString()
    }
}
```

Now its showing this error : error: Multiple methods define the same conversion. Conflicts with these: CustomTypeConverter

Please help. Thank you.

EDIT 2:

As per answer of richard slond, I have added the converter as

```
class ArrayConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun to(array: Array<String>): String {
        return array.joinToString(" ")
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun from(value: String): List<String> {
        return value.split(" ")
    }
}
```

and added in the database as

```
@Database(entities = [NewsArticles::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(ArrayConverters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun newsArticlesDao(): NewsArticlesDao
}
```

Also in the news article module

```
    @Entity(tableName = "news_table")
@TypeConverters(ArrayConverters::class)
data class NewsArticles(
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = "",
    @SerializedName("article_type") var title: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("abstract") var description: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("publication_date") var publishedAt: String? = null
)
```

Here for descriptionn variable if i have added string I am getting error as the field is begin with array.

and if i have specified as the arraylist it gives the error as can not add this type to the database please try using type converter.

What's missing??

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to store `Collection` (like `Array`, `List`) data into database is to convert them to `String` **In** `JSON` format, and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library (developed by Google) is designed for this situation.

**How to Use:**

```
String jsonString;

toJsonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        jsonString = gson.toJson(student);                  //object -> json
    }
});

toObjectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Student currentStudent = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Student.class);  //json -> object
    }
});
```

---

- **Reminder:** try to put your `Collection` into an `Object` (as a member variable), otherwise you may need following extra works:

**Get the Type for Your `Collection`:**

```
TypeToken<List<Integer>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){};

List<Integer> retrievedNumbers = gson.fromJson(numbersJsonString, typeToken.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you need to find a way to represent an array of strings using a primitive type. The easiest way is to use JSON format. For that reason, in your converter, you need to serialize and deserialize your string array.

As quick solution (which I do not recommend) is the following:

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun to(array: Array<String>): String {
        return array.joinToString(",")
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun from(value:String):  Array<String> {
        return value.split(",")
    }
```

Please be aware, following this path, your strings cannot include commas - but you can use another not so common character as separator

Comment: hi @richard soland , please check the edit I tried using your solution but still having error.